# low-reorder first or last page

Tags: low-reorder

I have a channel that is using {exp:low_reorder:next_entry} and {exp:low_reorder:prev_entry}

If I am on the first entries page I need to link to the last entry, then if I am on the last entry link back to the first.

So effectively allowing the user to continuously navigate and loop through all entries.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question (helps if you fully read the docs). The answer is simply

```
loop="yes"
```